# Learn how to use Solidity ( Error encoding arguments: Error: invalid BigNumber)

Tags: solidity, blockchain, compiler

Good afternoon folks! I thank the attention !
I'm taking a Solidity course that Microsoft made available on the link

https://aka.ms/SolidityHowTo-11

```
pragma solidity >0.7.0 <0.8.0;

contract Marketplace {
    address public seller;
    address public buyer;
    mapping (address => uint) public balances;

    event ListItem(address seller, uint price);
    event PurchasedItem(address seller, address buyer, uint price);

    enum StateType {
          ItemAvailable,
          ItemPurchased
    }

    StateType public State;

    constructor() public {
        seller = msg.sender;
        State = StateType.ItemAvailable;
    }

    function initialBalance(address participant, uint amount) public{
        require(msg.sender == participant, "you cannot uptdate someone else´s balance");
        balances[participant]=amount;
    }

    function buy(address seller, address buyer, uint price) public payable {
        require(price <= balances[buyer], "Insufficient balance");
        State = StateType.ItemPurchased;
        balances[buyer] -= price;
        balances[seller] += price;

        emit PurchasedItem(seller, buyer, msg.value);
    }
}
```

And I'm getting an error that I don't know what it's about because the code looks normal to me.

[image]

When compiling from Remix.ethereum it shows the error !
[image]

I don't know what this is, has anyone experienced this ? Thank you !

Comment: Can you show the contract code as well as the code to interact with it please ?

Comment: Yes , I put the contract code ! Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** : Modified my answer, @Adam Boudjemaa was right in his (deleted) answer, you did use `´` instead of `'` which appears to be an invalid character.

So as suggested, you can either change for `'` :

```
require(msg.sender == participant, "you cannot uptdate someone else's balance");
```

Or keep using `´` with the UTF-8 sequence code :

```
require(msg.sender == participant, "you cannot uptdate someone else\u00B4s balance");
```

Comment: Thank you ! It removed the compilation error but it is showing an error : transact to Marketplace.initialBalance errored: Error encoding arguments: Error: invalid BigNumber string (argument="value", value="", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bignumber/5.5.0)

Comment: The license is not mandatory, but you can add one by copying this line as the first one of your file : // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

Comment: That's what I thought about the license, the bignumber error can be from the account that I would be putting? I don't know, if you can clarify me, I would be grateful.

Comment: Ah yeah I forgot about that error, are you interacting with your contract from Remix or did you write some code for that in JS or Python for example ?

Comment: I'm using ENVIROMENT - JavaScript VM (London), is that it?

Comment: Nope, but it's okay I checked again you are trying to call the `balances` function. It's working fine on my side, this kind of error is typically because you entered wrong data in the input field of remix, can you tell me EXACTLY what data you are entering in the field next to the button to call `balances` ?

Comment: I don't know, you can see it in this picture  https://ibb.co/dLLVpYx

Comment: No error on my side with "0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4" , double check it if you still have the error, you can copy / paste it in the `balance` field on Remix and try again, probably just a typo.

Comment: balances  : 0x5B3...eddC4
initialBalance  : 0xAb8...35cb2

Comment: Thanks , I will check here ! It cost !

Comment: 'm leaving here a shared google driver video to show you what happens. Thank you ! https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LSL4zviW2YIOMmklTXRrnXCRqH4kNORN/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Sorry I forgot about your comment... You are getting the error because you are probably not adding the `amount` parameter, or at least not correctly. `initialbalance` expects two parameters `address participant` and `uint amount` so in Remix, to set the initial balance of account 0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4 to let's say 1000 Wei, you must enter "0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4, 1000" in the input field (note the amount after the coma).

Comment: Don;t input the double quotes `"` from my last comment, it's just to show you the text to input, ,so  literally enter : 0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4, 1000  or "0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4", "1000" if you whish to keep quotes for any reason.

Alternatively, you can click on the arrow just on the right of this input field that will display the two distinct inputs, it might be easier.

Comment: Tnank You ! resolve ! Best !